# dynamic constraints, stick a button to a part of image

Tags: swift, constraints

I got a picture that I want to stick a button to a part of it. I Tried many ways but non of them worked. 
[image]

I want the button to stick to the second circle no matter of screen size.
any advice?

Comment: which button you want to stick with second circle ?

Comment: non of them. I want to make a new button with clear background and stick it to second circle.

Comment: Then just make new button and add circle inside that button set clear background and set constraint on button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just have to add center vertically & center horizontally and equal height and equal width and then play with multiplier to make it where I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add 4 constraints to that another button as shown in below image:

[image]

After that just update another button frame and it will always stick to the first button.

Comment: this is just a picture. there is no button or anything else in it. I just want to add a  button with clear background to second circle so the second circle works like a button